# Provide a "Network Profile" link on chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, profile-page, network-profile

When we click on Avatar in a chat room, the information like: about, chat-user-profile, user-profile-on-parentsite etc. is shown.

I am **requesting to display a Network Profile link** in there (At the following section):

> [image]

Because Network Profile link is neither available at chat user profile.

Comment: Part of why this would be useful is that there's still an issue with users having no chat parent if they delete the account that *is* their chat parent, making it impossible to find their account on the network.

Comment: @Catija Also visit [Let's have better idea on how to get rid of the point of parent user in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290421/260388)

Comment: The network profile is available via the site profile.

Answer (score -2):

No. I really can't see how the network profile is relevant to chat.

Network profile is just an aggregated view of all the user's profile around the network. There is no "network chat".

If one want to reach a user's network profile when seeing him/her in chat, it's just two clicks away.

Comment: Not if the user's chat parent account is deleted. If that's the case, there's no way to find the user's account at all.